# Accessing a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-variables

How do you get and set CSS custom properties (those accessed with `var(…)` in the stylesheet) using JavaScript (plain or jQuery)?

Here is my unsuccessful try: clicking on the buttons changes the usual `font-weight` property, but not the custom `--mycolor` property:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { 
      --mycolor: yellow;
      background-color: var(--mycolor);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Let's try to make this text bold and the background red.</p>
  <button onclick="plain_js()">Plain JS</button>
  <button onclick="jQuery_()">jQuery</button>

  <script>
  function plain_js() { 
    document.body.style['font-weight'] = 'bold';
    document.body.style['--mycolor'] = 'red';
  };
  function jQuery_() {
    $('body').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    $('body').css('--mycolor', 'red');
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `var` supported in CSS?

Comment: @Gothdo Yes there is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables It is still experimental however. Also it's purpose is not meant for things that you change at run-time but for maintainability. If you want things you can change look at [attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Comment: TL;DR : `getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--x')`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use `document.body.style.setProperty('--name', value);`:

```
var bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
var fooBar = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--foo-bar'); //get

document.body.style.setProperty('--foo-bar', newValue);//set
```

Comment: Does the set also update all references to that variable in the CSS to?

Comment: It can be used as a global variable which can change without loading a new file CSS

Comment: For anyone who wants to get or set a property on the `<html>`-tag instead of the body: You can access it with `document.documentElement`.

Comment: How about styles inside shadow root?

Comment: querySelect your shadowDOM for `:root` and then get/set on that (this also works for regular documents, where `html` is the root element of a web document)

Answer (score 48):

### The native solution

The **standard methods** to get/set CSS3 variables are `.setProperty()` and `.getPropertyValue()`.

If your Variables are Globals (declared in `:root`), you can use the following, for getting and setting their values.

```
// setter
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--myVariable', 'blue');
// getter
document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--myVariable');
```

**However the getter will only return the value of a var, if has been set, using `.setProperty()`**. 
If has been  set through CSS declaration, will return `undefined`.  Check it in this example:

```js
let c = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--myVariable');
alert('The value of --myVariable is : ' + (c?c:'undefined'));
```

```css
:root{ --myVariable : red; }
div{ background-color: var(--myVariable); }
```

```html
  <div>Red background set by --myVariable</div>
```

To avoid that unexpected behavior you have to make use of the `getComputedStyle()`method , before calling `.getPropertyValue()`.
The getter will then, look like this:

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement,null).getPropertyValue('--myVariable');
```

***In my opinion, accessing CSS variables should be more simple, fast, intuitive and natural...***

---

### My personal approach

I've implemented `CSSGlobalVariables`a tiny (<3kb) javascript helper which automatically detects and packs into an Object all the active CSS global variables in a document, **for easier access & manipulation**.

```
// get the document CSS global vars
let cssVar = new CSSGlobalVariables();
// set a new value to --myVariable
cssVar.myVariable = 'red';
// get the value of --myVariable
console.log( cssVar.myVariable );
```

Any change applied to the Object properties, is translated automatically to the CSS variables.

**Available in** : https://github.com/colxi/css-global-variables

Comment: I like it for when you need to manipulate the variables in JS, but in my case I only needed to fetch the values. So instead of a full helper library, I just needed a single helper function returning `getComputedStyle(document.documentElement,null).getPropertyValue(varStr);`

Comment: I know this is an older question, but how would you go about changing the actual var(--varName) dynamically in the stylesheet to the value selected? If I wanted to serve the stylesheet to the user, I would want the user to see the actual color name or hex value instead of var(--varName). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59507329/10964617 for example

Comment: @Dave.Q I that case you could use Sass or Less, otherwise i don't see how to expose those values directly

Comment: @connexo exactly. It outputs `undefined` as expected. Read again the comment before the code snippet.

Comment: I had a look at the prototype but couldn't find anything. Does someone know if it is possible to get an array of ALL defined custom properties within a document via JavaScript?

Answer (score 5):

The following example illustrates how one may change the background using either JavaScript or jQuery, taking advantage of custom CSS properties known also as CSS variables (read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)). Bonus: the code also indicates how one may use a CSS variable to change the font color.

```js
function plain_js() { 
    // need DOM to set --mycolor to a different color 
    d.body.style.setProperty('--mycolor', 'red');
     
    // get the CSS variable ...
    bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
    fontcolor = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--font-color'); //get
 
    // ... reset body element to custom property's new value
    d.body.style.color = fontcolor;
    d.g("para").style["font-weight"] = "bold";
    this.style.display="none";
  };

  function jQuery_() {
    $("body").get(0).style.setProperty('--mycolor','#f3f');
    $("body").css("color",fontcolor);
    $("#para").css("fontWeight","bold");
    $(this).css("display","none");
  }
  
var bodyStyles = null;
var fontcolor = "";
var d = document;

d.g = d.getElementById;
d.g("red").addEventListener("click",plain_js);
d.g("pink").addEventListener("click",jQuery_);
```

```css
:root {
     --font-color:white;
     --mycolor:yellow;
    }
    body { 
      background-color: var(--mycolor);
      color:#090;
    }
    
    #para {
     font: 90% Arial,Helvetica;
     font-weight:normal;
    }
    
    #red {
      background:red;
    }
    
    #pink {
      background:#f3f;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="para">Let's try to make the background red or pink and change the text to white and bold.</p>
  <button id="red">Red</button>
  <button id="pink">Pink</button>
```

Note that with jQuery, in order to set the custom property to a differnt value, this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002667/change-css-variable-using-jquery/38002850#38002850) actually holds the answer.  It uses the body element's [get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method which allows access to the underlying DOM structure and returns the body element, thereby facilitating the code setting the custom property `--mycolor` to a new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getComputedStyle function to get css variables,Here is a example.

```js
const colors = document.querySelectorAll(".color");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
colors.forEach((color) => color.addEventListener("click", changeColor));

function changeColor(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  // get color
  const color = getComputedStyle(target).getPropertyValue("--clr");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

  // active color
  colors.forEach((color) => color.classList.remove("active"));
  target.classList.add("active");
  
  result.textContent = getComputedStyle(target).getPropertyValue("--clr")
  
}

result.textContent = "#1dd1a1";
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #1dd1a1;
}

.colors{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.color{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--clr);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: $time-unit;

  }
  .color.active{
    border: .2rem solid #333;
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
```

```html
<h1>Click to change Background</h1>
<section class="colors">
  <span class="color active" style="--clr: #1dd1a1"></span>
  <span class="color" style="--clr: #ff6b6b"></span>
  <span class="color" style="--clr: #2e86de"></span>
  <span class="color" style="--clr: #f368e0"></span>
  <span class="color" style="--clr: #ff9f43"></span>
</section>

Current Color: <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers involving `getPropertyValue()` are the correct ones if you want the raw string value of the variable. However, this raw string value:

- could be expressed in any units, and
- will not be evaluated if it is an expression, i.e. will return `"calc(1px + 1px)"` instead of `"2px"`.

If you need calc evaluation and/or unit normalization, here is a hack that will always give you pixels:

```js
function evaluateCssLength(lengthExpr, contextElem) {
    // getComputedStyle(…).getPropertyValue(…) returns the raw expression for a CSS calc value,
    // i.e. a string of the form "calc(…)"
    //
    // To evaluate the calc, we create a temporary element and give it a max-width, which is a CSS
    // property that (1) expects a length and (2) will always resolve to the same actual pixel value
    // regardless of its containing element and surrounding CSS. We read the max-width back, now
    // computed and expressed as pixels, then discard the element.

    const measureElem = document.createElement("div");
    contextElem.appendChild(measureElem);
    measureElem.style.maxWidth = lengthExpr;
    const length = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(measureElem).maxWidth);
    contextElem.removeChild(measureElem);
    return length;
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
const containerElem = document.querySelect(".whatever");

// All the following will return pixels expressed as a float:
evaluateCssLength("37em", containerElem)
evaluateCssLength("var(--some-property)", containerElem)
evaluateCssLength("calc(100vh - 17ex * var(-foo))", containerElem)
```