# Change CSS variable using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, variables

Is it possible to change a variable used in CSS using jQuery?
Simple example:

```css
html {
  --defaultColor: teal;
}
.box {
  background: var(--defaultColor);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.circle {
  background: #eee;
  border: 2px solid var(--defaultColor);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickToChange" type="button" style="width: 100%;">Click to Change</button>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<br/>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

How can I change the variable color from teal to red for example? This one doesn't work.

```
$("#clickToChange").click(function(){
  $(html).css("--defaultColor", "red");
});
```

Comment: Here is my monkey patch of css method so you can use css variables with `.css` method https://gist.github.com/jcubic/9ef9fa2561de8430e953e2fe62011c20

Comment: @jcubic I'd say that this should be posted as a separate answer since none of other answers addresses the "chain jQuery methods issue", so I can't write `$(body).css('--css-var', 'var-value').html('This is body element').addClass('some-class')`.

Comment: @izogfif this is outdated question you can now use jQuery with CSS properties I think it was added in 3.4 version and you should use 3.5 because there was vulnerability in <3.5

Comment: **Set a single css variable/property:** `$(":root").css("--defaultColor", "red");`  . . . or you can **Set multiple css variables:** `$(":root").css({"--myVar0":myVal0, "--myVar1":myVal1});`, etc...   much tidier than non-jQuery solutions IMHO. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048660/8112776)).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You may change the css variable using plain JavaScript `elem.style.setProperty("variableName", "variableProp");`

```js
$("html").on('click', function() {
  
  $("body").get(0).style.setProperty("--color", "hotpink");
  
});
```

```css
body {
  --color: blue;
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

click me!
```

Comment: In jquery, you can do : $("html").attr("style","--defaultColor:hotpink");

Comment: Nicely done, I honestly didn't think that this is, or would be, possible without some use of regular expressions! I'm glad to have been proven wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks both @MattDiMu and @ DinoMyte for working solutions.

Comment: @DinoMyte's is the only one that worked for me. I'm a total jQuery Noob, so this is the kind of help I need.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I created a radial progress bar for my app and this was the answer I needed to set the progress in motion :-)

Answer (score 2):

See question [Setting a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/setting-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript-or-jquery)

The method in question is `document.body.style.setProperty($property, value);` where **$property** is the CSS variable.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution IMHO: Change a class, that in turn changes the default color:

```css
html {
  --defaultColor: teal;
}
html.someOtherDefaultColor {
  --defaultColor: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```js
$("#clickToChange").click(function(){
  $(html).toggleClass("someOtherDefaultColor");
});
```

Comment: That what I was thinking too.

Comment: While this provides a functioning solution, and answers the second part of the question, it rather avoids answering the first question that was asked.

Comment: @DavidThomas, granted, but also, _that depends_ - it might as well solve the underlying problem (of simply getting this done) that was asked for. And in most places where it is possible to achieve something like this in this way, many also consider it to be the preferable way, regarding separation of concerns.

Comment: Oh, I fully agree with the solution, and it's certainly easier than trying to access and change CSS variables directly.

Comment: @DavidThomas it is possible as i've just shown below and there are many use-cases where you should do it. E.g. when you don't have a fixed set of possible values, because the user may choose a color himself.

Comment: @Matt: indeed you have, and I already commented on that answer.

Comment: But with this solution it would not be possible to do calculations via js, for example, would it? (even this might actually not be part of this specific question)