# How to get :root selector info from Bootstrap 4 programmatically?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In each bootstrap 4 CSS files, we have `:root` selector like

```
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
  --red: #dc3545;
  --orange: #fd7e14;
  --yellow: #ffc107;
  --green: #28a745;
  --teal: #20c997;
  --cyan: #17a2b8;
  --white: #fff;
  --gray: #868e96;
  --gray-dark: #343a40;
  --primary: #007bff;
  --secondary: #868e96;
  --success: #28a745;
  --info: #17a2b8;
  --warning: #ffc107;
  --danger: #dc3545;
  --light: #f8f9fa;
  --dark: #343a40;
  --breakpoint-xs: 0;
  --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
  --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

Is there any way to get that by javascript programmatically?

I want to have this information based on each CSS template programmatically.

I can parse the `.css` file for that but it is ugly!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002667/change-css-variable-using-jquery

Comment: these are called CSS variable and you can find what you need in the link above ;)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with it?

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's typically better not to mark the question as a duplicate of a second question also closed as a duplicate. Follow the trail to the ultimate target and mark this question as a dupe of *that* one.

Comment: @TylerH yes true, but i always try to get all the questions that ca be possible duplicates (even if they are also duplicates) because i know that we can make question to have many dupes. So if a gold CSS is here he will add all of them ;) but yes i should have choosed the second one