# Change CSS theme variable values with JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-variables

How can I change the value of the variables inside this block `[user-theme="theme"]` with JS? I have the same variables in other blocks that should not be affected because I flip between them by changing the attribute value.

```
[user-theme="theme"] {
   --cell-checked-in: red;
   --cell-checked-out: grey;
   --cell-online-booking: yellow;
   --cell-offline-booking: white;
}
```

The one solution I found that works (partly) is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002850/2529106) but it adds inline styles in the HTML tag which I don't want. I also can't do something like `$("html[user-theme=theme]").get(0).style.setProperty("--cell-online-booking", "red");`

Comment: Don't change the values in CSS using JS. The correct pattern to use here would be to define a new `user-theme` value and hook a new set of CSS rules to that, no JS involved.

Comment: @freedomn-m - this helps assuming my variables are set in :root but my variables are inside [user-theme="theme"]. How do I target that if it's possible at all. Out of interest sake.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - you are correct and I have been staring at this so long I've lost track of what I'm supposed to be doing and started creating problems to solve that I shouldn't have to.

Comment: "The one solution I found that works (partly) is this one but it adds inline styles in the HTML tag which I don't want." — That's how CSS variables are designed to work. You could change the rulesets themselves, but that would be needlessly complex.

Comment: `$("html[user-theme=theme]").get(0).style` could be simplified to `document.documentElement.style`

Comment: @wind_kind — If you change the `user-theme` attribute (which is invalid HTML and should be a `data-` attribute or a class), then the ruleset with the `[user-theme="theme"]` will no longer apply, and the ruleset with the `[user-theme="different-theme-entirely"]` that you would have added in response to the second half of Rory's initial comment would instead.