# Using CSS3 Variables in Knockout Style Binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout's [style binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) to add [CSS3 variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) to some `div` elements, which are then used in our CSS to compute the final styles.

Example:

```js
var viewModel = function ViewModel() {
  this.randomColor = ko.computed(function() {
    // Random color thanks to @paul_irish
    return "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  });
}();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
h2 {
  /* default fall-back color: */
  --random-colour: #666;
  color: var(--random-colour);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2 data-bind="style: {'--random-colour': randomColor}">This should receive a random text color.</h2>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tujhxdmc/5/

I would expect it to apply the css variable in a style tag, but instead it just seems to be ignored. The surrounding bindings and bindings using standard CSS properties are all working as expected, so I'm certain that it's a problem with CSS variables.

[Knockout's documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) states:

> If you want to apply a font-weight or text-decoration style, or any other style whose name isn’t a legal JavaScript identifier (e.g., because it contains a hyphen), you must use the JavaScript name for that style. For example,
>
> - Don’t write { font-weight: someValue }; do write { fontWeight: someValue }

But that doesn't work for CSS variables (which must be proceeded by a double-hyphen).

**How do you use CSS variables in Knockout's style binding?**

Comment: Looking at the source, I don't think this is going to be supported in any pretty way if at all without a pull request: [defaultBindings/style.js](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/9eb61061e45e371362aee8d182392c531b7ac2ef/src/binding/defaultBindings/style.js#L15).

Comment: That seems to be the line that camel-cases style properties but it looks like the `--` will get eaten by the RegEx.

Comment: ..I don't really like the look of that

Comment: I made an issue to track this on the GitHub.  You can find it here: [Cannot bind to custom CSS property variables #2400](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2400).  Maybe a better approach will come from that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this won't be possible right now without augmentation of Knockout.

Consider how style bindings are actioned right now in the source here:  [knockout/src/binding/defaultBindings/style.js](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/9eb61061e45e371362aee8d182392c531b7ac2ef/src/binding/defaultBindings/style.js#L15-L24)
.

Particularly this line:

```
 element.style[styleName] = styleValue;
```

Whenever this runs, `styleName` will be the CSS variable `"--random-colour"`.

However, you can't set the style through `element.style["--random-colour"]`.  You have to go through [`style.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Values_in_JavaScript).

Consider also this question: [Accessing a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419028/691711)

---

If you need this functionality right now, you could load the knockout library script and then override the `ko.bindingHandlers['style'].update` function to use a version that will use `setProperty()`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['style'] = {
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
        ko.utils.objectForEach(value, function(styleName, styleValue) {
            styleValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(styleValue);

            if (styleValue === null || styleValue === undefined || styleValue === false) {
                // Empty string removes the value, whereas null/undefined have no effect
                styleValue = "";
            }

            if(styleName.substring(0, 2) === "--"){
                element.style.setProperty(styleName, styleValue);
            } else {
                element.style[styleName] = styleValue;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

---

I have added an issue on the KnockOut GitHub in case other, better responses come from there: [Cannot bind to custom CSS property variables #2400](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2400).

Comment: You do not need to fork Knockout to add binding handlers.

Comment: @MichaelBest Could you add how as an answer? I agree that forking is overkill if you can override the default behavior.

Comment: After including the Knockout library, include your code above. You will then have replaced the `style` binding handler with your own.

Comment: @MichaelBest You're right, that is a much better interim solution.