# Using javascript, how do I make CSS variables overwrite stick via onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript), I'm able to change CSS variables, via onclick of a nav link.  But, the changes are not sticking.  They will momentarily switch to the new styles, but then flip back to the originals.  This is even without a page refresh--a second after onmouseup.

Thank you.

CSS

```
body {

    --bg-color-home: rgba(221, 230, 237, .85);
    --bg-image-home: url(../images/bg_peak.jpg);

    --bg-color-about: rgba(223, 238, 243, 1);
    --bg-image-about: url(../images/bg_about.jpg);

    --bg-color: var(--bg-color-home);
    --bg-image: var(--bg-image-home);    
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="template.xhtml?page=about" data-value="about" class="nav-link">About</a>
```

JavaScript

```
//Change CSS styles, based on 'link' variable
$(document).on('click','a.nav-link',function(){

    //Set link variable from 'data-value' of 'nav-link' option
    var link = $("a:focus").attr('data-value');

    //Set the new styles based on 'nav-link' option
    $(document.body).css('--bg-color', 'var(--bg-color-' + link + ')');
    $(document.body).css('--bg-image', 'var(--bg-image-' +  link + ')');

});
```

Comment: What do you expect to see after clicking on the link?

Comment: Clicking on the link navigates to the new page, so none of the style changes you make on this page have any effect.

Comment: Those style don't look like normal CSS styles. What is `--bg-color-home`?

Comment: Are they not sticking because the page then goes to the about page? Your css looks a bit odd there are easier ways to give your nav buttons an active/current style. Can you use php?

Comment: @Barmar, right, the changes are not sticking.  I had just assumed setting new values via javascript would overwrite the original and stick until a new onclick changes them.  This is what I'm attempting do, and am searching out.  Any thoughts are welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: When you follow a link the page is totally reloaded, and nothing from the previous page is retained except for cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage.

Comment: Ok, I'll research those aspects, as well as the solution provided by dysfunc below.  Thank you for the follow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the global variables to the `background-color` and `background-image` CSS props so any future reassignment of global CSS variable value reflects properly.

CSS

```
body {
  --bg-color-home: rgba(221, 230, 237, .85);
  --bg-image-home: url(../images/bg_peak.jpg);

  --bg-color-about: rgba(223, 238, 243, 1);
  --bg-image-about: url(../images/bg_about.jpg);

  --bg-color: var(--bg-color-home);
  --bg-image: var(--bg-image-home);   

  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  background-image: var(--bg-image);
}
```

JS

```
// cache body ref
var body = $(document.body);

$('.nav-link').on('click', function(e){
  // this should be removed if you want the page to change
  e.preventDefault();
  // ref page
  var page = $(this).data('value');
  // update global vars
  body
    .attr('style', '--bg-color: var(--bg-color-' + page + ')')
    .attr('style', '--bg-image: var(--bg-image-' + page + ')');
});
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLwoar)

Comment: I had to edit the answer - there was a typo. Answer and demo have been updated.

Comment: Within the context of your demo, that works--thank you.  Maybe I wasn't clear, but I'm wanting these CSS variables to be global; so, as --bg-color and --bg-image are updated via onclick, it will globally effect all instances of the variables, not just body. I can move them to root, if that is best practice for global variables, though I've read that body or root is ok. 
I thank you for your help and welcome any other thoughts.

Comment: updated the demo with a couple options for controlling the global var

Comment: to confirm, I can get the variables to change via onclick, but not stick upon navigation/refresh.  I welcome any thoughts or recommendations. P.S. I posted this prior to seeing your new comment.  I'll take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do now. I've updated the demo and answer. You you need to ref the global vars in actual properties ` background-color: var(--bg-color);` so when you modify the value everything updates correctly. See changes in the CSS and review the demo

Comment: Ok, I see that it's working on your demo, but couldn't replicate it locally.  I'll play with this and let you know.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: no problem. let me know if you need help figuring anything out

Comment: ok, I was finally able to get this work locally.  Some of the issues were: 1) I'm using jquery includes for the nav (where the links are), so using the listener (deferred?) from my original code, remedied that; 2) the short-hand used for your setter was not setting both color and image--only either or, depending on which was the last listed and with the closing semi-colon.  So, using my original setters remedied that. 3) Also, removing the preventDefault didn't allow for the overwrite to take--so, I've kept that for now.

Comment: Now, I need to use session variables, or whatever is best practice, to keep styles accurate for the current page, even upon refresh, as Barmar suggested.  I welcome any thoughts you may have, but won't hold you to anything, as you've already contributed plenty.  You've been a great help-- thank you.