# How to use CSS to store color variables to be picked up and rendered via js to create a chart.js

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a basic dashboard of charts, using chart.js to render the data. I have a javasciprt per chart that gets the data and draws each chart to the dashboard (so that I can create multiple dashboards, and re use certain charts wherever.) I want to be able to store a list of colours in css, so that charts can use the same colours to represent the same item, even when in a different style of chart.

Ive looked into using :root in css and using the get property value to retrieve the variable, but this doesn't seem to work. Am I going about this the right way?

CSS:

```css
:root {
 --mediumRiskColour: blue;
}
```

Javascript to get the variable:

```
var mediumRiskColour =     getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--mediumRiskColour');
```

// Javascript to then use this variable in the chart:

```
{
label: 'Medium risk
data: mediumRisk,
borderColor: 'mediumRiskColour',
backgroundColor: 'mediumRiskColour',
},
```

I would like the colour to be pulled from the css so that I can use it to colour items in a chart that is rendered in javascript

Comment: It should work this way, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419028/10955263 Question would be, did you get the timing right, is this CSS already applied at the time you try to read this value?

Comment: I use the <body onload="function()"> to call a function that then calls the functions required to draw the charts - I presume that the css has loaded once the body has loaded?