# How to generate CSS variable values to a new stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a project in which a user can select colors from a color input and create their own theme dynamically using CSS variables. I'd like the user to be able to download the entire CSS file with the values they selected.

**My issue**: The CSS file downloaded doesn't display the actual color values, but shows the variable name.

```
NOT WANTED

pre[class*="language-"] {
  background: var(--block-background);
}
```

instead of

```
WANTED OUTPUT

pre[class*="language-"] {
  background: #0D2831;
}
```

I know I can get CSS property values by doing the following.

```
const styles = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
const value = String(styles.getPropertyValue('--block-background')).trim()
```

I figured that I would create a function that loops through all my CSS variables and grabs the corresponding property values and then adds them to a new stylesheet for the user to download, but I got lost along the way. I currently have two CSS files, a `main.css` and a `prism.css`. The `main.css` file holds the page styling and all CSS variables within the root. The `prism.css` file contains the theme in which I want the user to be able to download.

I'm trying to find a way to create a new stylesheet that contains everything within the `prism.css` file but has the actual color hex code instead of the CSS variable name as a value to the given CSS property.

**Index.js**

```
import { colors } from './colorHelper'

const inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="color"]'));

const handleThemeUpdate = (colors) => {
  const root = document.querySelector(':root');
  const keys = Object.keys(colors);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    root.style.setProperty(key, colors[key]);
  });
}

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const cssPropName = `--${e.target.id}`;
    document.styleSheets[2].cssRules[3].style.setProperty(cssPropName, e.target.value)
    handleThemeUpdate({
      [cssPropName]: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(`${cssPropName} is now ${e.target.value}`)
  });
});


const cssRules = document.styleSheets[2].cssRules;
for (var i = 0; i < cssRules.length; i++) {
  // Finds css variable names
  const regexp = /(?:var\(--)[a-zA-z\-]*(?:\))/

  let cssVariables = cssRules[i].cssText.matchAll(regexp)
  cssVariables = Array.from(cssVariables).join()

  console.log(cssVariables)
}
```

**colorHelper.js**

```
const colorSelect = {
  'Line Highlights': {
    'highlight-background': '#F7EBC6',
    'highlight-accent': '#F7D87C'
  },
  'Inline Code': {
    'inline-code-color': '#DB4C69',
    'inline-code-background': '#F9F2F4'
  },
  'Code Blocks': {
    'block-background': '#0D2831',
    'base-color': '#5C6E74',
    'selected-color': '#b3d4fc'
  },
  'Tokens': {
    'comment-color': '#93A1A1',
    'punctuation-color': '#999999',
    'property-color': '#990055',
    'selector-color': '#669900',
    'operator-color': '#a67f59',
    'operator-background': '#FFFFFF',
    'variable-color': '#ee9900',
    'function-color': '#DD4A68',
    'keyword-color': '#0077aa'
  }
}

const colorNames = []
const colors = {}

Object.keys(colorSelect).map(key => {
  const group = colorSelect[key]
  Object.keys(group).map(color => {
    colorNames.push(color)
    colors[color] = group[color]
  })
})

export { colorSelect, colorNames, colors }
```

**prism.css**

```
pre[class*="language-"],
code[class*="language-"] {
  color: var(--base-color);
  font-size: 13px;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre;
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  -o-tab-size: 4;
  tab-size: 4;
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  -moz-hyphens: none;
  -ms-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
}
pre[class*="language-"]::selection,
code[class*="language-"]::selection,
pre[class*="language-"]::mozselection,
code[class*="language-"]::mozselection {
  text-shadow: none;
  background: var(--selected-color);
}

@media print {
  pre[class*="language-"],
  code[class*="language-"] {
    text-shadow: none;
  }
}

pre[class*="language-"] {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: var(--block-background);
}
:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
  padding: .1em .3em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  color: var(--inline-code-color);
  background: var(--inline-code-background);
}

/* Tokens */

.namespace {
  opacity: .7;
}
.token.comment,
.token.prolog,
.token.doctype,
.token.cdata {
  color: var(--comment-color);
}
.token.punctuation {
  color: var(--punctuation-color);
}
.token.property,
.token.tag,
.token.boolean,
.token.number,
.token.constant,
.token.symbol,
.token.deleted {
  color: var(--property-color);
}
.token.selector,
.token.attr-name,
.token.string,
.token.char,
.token.builtin,
.token.inserted {
  color: var(--selector-color);
}
.token.operator,
.token.entity,
.token.url,
.language-css .token.string,
.style .token.string {
  color: var(--operator-color);
  background: var(--operator-background);
}
.token.atrule,
.token.attr-value,
.token.keyword {
  color: var(--keyword-color);
}
.token.function {
  color: var(--function-color);
}
.token.regex,
.token.important,
.token.variable {
  color: var(--variable-color);
}
.token.important,
.token.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.token.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
.token.entity {
  cursor: help;
}

/* Line highlighting */

pre[data-line] {
  position: relative;
}
pre[class*="language-"] > code[class*="language-"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.line-highlight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: inherit 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: var(--highlight-background);
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 var(--highlight-accent);
  z-index: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

I have three stylesheets.

`style.css` holds the CSS variables in the root

`normalize.css`

`prism.css` contains the styles for syntax highlighting. This is the stylesheet I would like the user to download, but I would like to provide them with the actual hex values for each variable and not the variable name for the CSS property.

**Stylesheet order in my HTML**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css"
    integrity="sha256-WAgYcAck1C1/zEl5sBl5cfyhxtLgKGdpI3oKyJffVRI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="./themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**EDIT**

I attempted to loop through the stylesheet and grab the CSS variable names, but some of them returned as an empty string.

**This is what I did**

```
const cssRules = document.styleSheets[2].cssRules;
for (var i = 0; i < cssRules.length; i++) {
  const regexp = /(?:var\(--)[a-zA-z\-]*(?:\))/

  let cssVariables = cssRules[i].cssText.matchAll(regexp)
  cssVariables = Array.from(cssVariables)

  console.log(cssVariables)
}
```

This was the result in the console

```
var(--base-color) 
var(--selected-color) 
<empty string>
var(--block-background)
var(--inline-code-color)
<empty string>
var(--comment-color)
var(--punctuation-color)
var(--property-color) 
var(--selector-color)
var(--operator-color)
var(--keyword-color) 
var(--function-color)
var(--variable-color) 
<empty string> 
var(--highlight-background)
```

I then attempted to chain `.replace()` after the `trim()` but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Have you tried doing a simple find and replace?

Comment: I would loop through all CSS values that are variables and replace them with the value chosen, but how would I maintain everything from the original stylesheet while appending the new values?

Comment: Your regex is invalid, I made one that might work better: https://regexr.com/4rgj2

Comment: @Dave.Q you "attempted to loop through the stylesheet"... can we see this stylesheet, please?

Comment: @x00 No problem. I've edited my question and included the stylesheet and other related information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the file as text then find and replace the variables.

For example:

```js
var s = `pre[class*="language-"] {
  background: var(--block-background);
}`

const variables = {"block-background":"#0D2831"};

Object.keys(variables).forEach(key => {
  s = s.replace("var(--"+key+")", variables[key]); 
});

console.log(s);
```

Comment: I edited my original question with an attempt I made. Upon looping through the stylesheet to find a matching regex for the CSS variables, I was given an empty array for each. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are getting empty strings from css rules that do not have `var(--something)` in them. Like

   ```
   @media print {
     pre[class*="language-"],
     code[class*="language-"] {
       text-shadow: none;
     }
   }
   ```

   which gives you the first empty string.
2. You are missing `var(--operator-background)` because `matchAll()` actually doesn't do what you expect. It does

   > returns an iterator of all results matching a string against a regular expression

   but the regular expression you have yields only one result. So you need to add `g` flag to it

   `/(?:var\(--)[a-zA-z\-]*(?:\))/g`
3. `mozselection`... Hmm... Not sure, but shouldn't it be `-moz-selection`?
4. The full loop for replacements can look like this:

   ```
    const updated_rules = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < cssRules.length; i++) {
       const regexp = /(?:var\(--)[a-zA-z\-]*(?:\))/g;
       let updated_rule = cssRules[i].cssText;
       let cssVariables = updated_rule.matchAll(regexp);
       cssVariables = Array.from(cssVariables).flat();
       for (const v of cssVariables) {
         updated_rule = updated_rule.replace(v, colors[v.slice(6, -1)]);
       }
       updated_rules.push(updated_rule);
     }
     console.log(updated_rules);
   ```

   It's an ugly code, and should be refactored, but...
5. Why would you access css through `document.styleSheets` anyway? It's harder than just replacing strings in a css-file and for one thing, I'm not sure if you whould be able to access `::-moz-selection` rule on Chrome, and in turn `::-webkit-selection` on Firefox

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. My question to the last point in your answer is how would I change strings in a CSS file? I'm just looking for a way for the user to choose their own colors and then download the stylesheet with his/her selected styles. I'm assuming replace the strings in the file and add the updated styles to a new style tag in the head? I'm a bit lost on this one.

Comment: @Dave.Q just get prism.css strait from your server and replace variables. Like so:
`async function get_css_and_replace_vars() {
  const res = await fetch("./prism.css");
  const orig_css = await res.text();
  let updated_css = orig_css;
  const regexp = /(?:var\(--)[a-zA-z\-]*(?:\))/g;
  let cssVars = orig_css.matchAll(regexp);
  cssVars = Array.from(cssVars).flat();
  for (const v of cssVars) updated_css = updated_css.replace(v, colors[v.slice(6, -1)]);
  console.log(updated_css);
  ...
}`
What you do with original prims.css and with an updated version of it is up to you.

Comment: And yes, you can do exactly as you said.

Comment: I'm using Parcel to bundle everything and it's giving me an error because the `href` I've provided isn't found since I'm creating the style tag through JavaScript. `const createStyleSheet = () => {
  const css = document.createElement('style');
  css.type = 'text/css'
  css.href = 'prism.css'
  css.innerHTML = get_css_and_replace_vars()

  const script = document.querySelector('script')
  script.parentNode.insertBefore(css, script)
}`. My download button looks like this `<a id="download-btn" download href="prism.css">Download CSS</a>`

Comment: @Dave.Q, sorry didn't really get what you mean. Is you issue with user downloading already updated css, or is it with creating a style tag. But as I see it now, you maybe have both :) ...why would you need to set href at all, if you use innerHTML. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top If not, can you post it as another question with more details?

Comment: My issue is with downloading the updated CSS. I figured I would create a style tag and inject the updated styles. Then I would use the href on the new style element to correspond with that of the download button, but it didn't work as I was given an error stating that prism. CSS isn't available. I'm more than certain I'm going about this wrong or missing something. I returned the `updated_css` from the `get_css..` function and applied it to the innerHTML and figured I could just download the script tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server