# How to access css variable defined within css class from javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

I have css variables defined within a css class.

```
.popup {
    --popup-opacity: 0;
    --popup-visibility: hidden;
    opacity: var(--popup-opacity);
    visibility: var(--popup-visibility);
}
```

I want to update this using javascript. The following code works if variables are within root element:

```
 document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--popup-opacity', 1);
 document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--popup-visibility', 'visible');
```

I cannot figure out how to make it work when variables are defined within the css class. Please help.

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is how inheritance in JS works.

If you've set the value of the variable in the rule-set with the class selector then that element won't inherit from higher up the DOM.

It's the same issue you would get if you set `.popup { color: red; }` and then wondered why it remains red is you set `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('color', "red");`

Define your variables higher up the DOM:

```
html {
    --popup-opacity: 0;
    --popup-visibility: hidden;
}

.popup {
    opacity: var(--popup-opacity);
    visibility: var(--popup-visibility);
}
```

and then override them at the same level or one between it and where they are read:

```
 document.body.style.setProperty('--popup-opacity', 1);
 document.body.style.setProperty('--popup-visibility', 'visible');
```