# Use a css variable in jQuery .animate

Tags: jquery, css

For some reason, in the JQuery the .animate doesn't work when using a variable into it, so the size and the position doesn't change into the second animate. The rest of the values like "60px" work, but that doesn't. I think it can be because it is not a number, but I don't know how to fix it. Ignore the //, they are only failed tests.

```js
var ptop = 0;
var pleft = 0;
var este
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.a').click(function() {
    este = $(this);
    ptop = ($(this).css("top"))+"px";
    pleft = ($(this).css("left"))+"px";
    $(".a").not($(this)).fadeOut("500");
    jQuery.when(($(".a").not($(this))).fadeOut("500")).then(function(){
      este.show().stop(true).animate({
        height: "700px",
        width: "700px",
        top: "50px",
        left: "50px",
        "pointer-events": "none",
      }, 500);
      este.css({"pointer-events":"none",});
      $("#"+este.attr("title")).fadeIn("500");
      /*jQuery.when($("#"+este.attr("title")).fadeIn("500")).then(function(){
        $(this).stop()
      });*/
    });
    $("#cerrar").hide().delay("500").fadeIn("500");
    $(".b").hide().delay(500).fadeIn("500");
  });
  $("#cerrar").click(function() {
    var este = $(".a").not(":hidden");
    let topp = este.css("--top");
    let sizze = este.css("--size");
    let lefft = este.css("--left");
    //$(".a").not(":hidden").fadeOut("500");
    $(".b").fadeOut("500");
    $("#"+$(".a").not(":hidden").attr("title")).fadeOut("500");
    //$(".a").css({"height": "var(--size)", "width": "var(--size)", "position":"absolute", "top":"var(--top)","left":"var(--left)","pointer-events":"all",}).fadeIn("500");
    $(".a").stop(true).animate({
      height: sizze,
      width: sizze,
      top: topp,
      left: lefft,
      "pointer-events":"all",
    },
    500
  );
    $(this).fadeOut("200");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.b {
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  left:800px;
  top:50px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 10% 2% 10% 10%;
}
.p,
.s {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.sol {
  --size: 100px;
  --top: 400px;
  --left: 400px;
  top: var(--top);
  left: var(--left);
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/The_Sun_by_the_Atmospheric_Imaging_Assembly_of_NASA%27s_Solar_Dynamics_Observatory_-_20100819.jpg/220px-The_Sun_by_the_Atmospheric_Imaging_Assembly_of_NASA%27s_Solar_Dynamics_Observatory_-_20100819.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.mercurio {
  --size: 20px;
  --top: 200px;
  --left: 200px;
  top: var(--top);
  left: var(--left);
  background-image: url(http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2016/04/mercury_globe/15922572-1-eng-GB/Mercury_Globe_pillars.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.venus {
  --size: 40px;
  --top: 100px;
  --left: 100px;
  top: var(--top);
  left: var(--left);
  background-image: url(https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/09/14/science/15venus-es-00/14SCI-VENUS1-alt-superJumbo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  top: 100px;
}
.left {
  float: none;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
agrandar {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  "pointer-events": none;
}
#cerrar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/PlayStation_button_X.svg/1024px-PlayStation_button_X.svg.png");
  border-radius: 0%;
  top: 55px;
  left: 1475px;
  background-size: cover;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;

}
#Sol {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 420px;
  width:650px;
  color: white;
  top:75px;
  left:825px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Sistema Solar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="a s sol 1" title="Sol" >  </div>
  <div class="a p mercurio 2" title="Mercurio" >  </div>
  <div class="a p venus 3" title="Venus"> </div>
  <div class="b"> </div>
  <div class="c" id="cerrar">  </div>
  <div class="1" id="Sol">
    <p style="font-size: 64px ;text-align:center; margin: 0 0 0 0;"> <b>El Sol</b> </p>
    <p><span class="left"> Clasificación: </span> <span class="right"> Estrella "enana amarilla" </span></p>
    <p><span class="left"> Ubicación: </span> <span class="right"> Centro del Sistema Solar </span></p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you can do without CSS variables. Specify individual parameters (height, width, left, top) for each animated element.

You can use the general class of all animated elements, by clicking on which you get the desired parameters (height, width, left, top) of the current element through the `css()` method.

For example:

```
$(".a").on("click", function () {
    let height_size = $(this).css("height");
    let width_size = $(this).css("width");
    let left_size = $(this).css("left");
    let top_size = $(this).css("top");
    ...
```

Next, pass these values to the `animate()` method.

```
$(".a").animate(
    {
        height: height_size,
        width: width_size,
        top: top_size,
        left: left_size,
        pointer-events: "all",
    },500);
```

Comment: The variables change depends of element, how can i put that? With that it still doesn't work

Comment: @JibriI, Then make a reproducible example, pls. Or add css, html, which can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JibriI, This won't work - `var este = $(".a").not(":hidden"); let topp = este.css("--top");...`. Also, add css and html.

Comment: I have put the complete file now

Comment: It had a bad URL so I have changed it another time

Comment: @JibriI, Why did you choose css variables for dynamic values for animate()?

Comment: Should I use directly JQuery variables?

Comment: I'm new at this and I don't know so much. In that case, how can I make the value of the variable be different in each element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231953/discussion-between-s-kuznetsov-and-jibrii).