# How to use SCSS variables in a Javascript visual effect

Tags: javascript, css, variables, sass

I'm trying to build on a Javascript lava lamp visual effect to use colours set from the SCSS rather than in the JS code snippet.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nathanlong/pen/PoxrEOJ)

**CSS**

```
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #ffffff;
}
```

**JS**

```
// Make a nice color pallete for our random orbs 
const colors = ["0x4361ee", "0x3a0ca3", "0x7209b7", "0xf72585"]; const blurFilter2 = new PIXI.BlurFilter();
```

I wish for the JS #4361ee, #3a0ca3 to be replaced with --white and --black

Comment: please be aware that `--black` and `--white` are not a SCSS vairables. They are CSS custom properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript)

Comment: Great. I think so, Im struggling to visualise this into the context of the Codepen though

Comment: This is what I believe the other post is advising to do, https://codepen.io/cleaton/pen/NWJMyGG  but I'm unable to see my obvious mistakes.